# The sup{(n-1)/n : n is a natural number} exists?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

True or False?

a)The $\sup \{\frac{(n-1)}{n} : n\in\mathbb{B} \}$ exists?

b) If ${x_n}$ is a sequence with $x_n < 3$ for all $n$, then it cannot converge to $3$?

For a) True: By definition, the number $s$ is called the supremum of a set $E$ if 1) $S$ is an upper bound for $E$. And 2) If $t$ is an upper bound for $E$, then $s \leq t$.

Then take $\sup \{1 - \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.
Then we can see that $1$ is an upper bound for the set. And if $t$ is an upper bound for the set, then $1 \leq$ for all $t$.

For b) True : Take $x_n = (-1)^(n)$ , then this is bounded above by $1$ and bounded below by $-1$, then $x_n < 3$. Then it cannot converge to $3$.

Can someone please verify this?

Thank you.

Comment: What if your sequence if $x_n = 3 - \frac{1}{n}$ for (b)?

Comment: Your reasoning for (b) fails because you found a *specific* sequence. However, (b) says for *all* sequences with the property $x_n <3$ for all $n$ then they cannot converge to $3$.

Comment: Note that $\sup S$ exists for *every* set $S\subseteq\mathbb R$, though $\sup S$ need not be finite.

Answer (score 2):

a) is true. 1 is supremum.

b) is not true. For example, let $x_n=3-\frac1n<3$, however, it converges to 3.

Answer (score 0):

a) Observe that $(n-1)/n \leq 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ implies that its supremum exists.

Your argument for (a) is too strong (showing that an upper bound exists would suffice). You also need to justify that if $t$ is an upper bound, then $t \geq 1$.

b) False. Take $x_n = 3 - n^{-1}$.

The problem with your argument is that a theorem cannot be proved by example, but *can* be proved false with one counterexample.